# $A,B \in M_3(\mathbb{R}) $ such that $A,B$ are symmetric. Find all values of $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A^k , B^k$ are congruent.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, matrix-congruences

$A,B \in M_3(\mathbb{R}) $ such that $A,B$ are symmetric.

$P_A(x)=x^3-x$ (the characteristic polynomial of $A$).

$P_B(y)=y^3-3y^2+2y$ (the characteristic polynomial of $B$).

Find all values of $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A^k , B^k$ are congruent.

My solution :

$P_A(x)=x^3-x=0 \implies x_{1}=0,x_{2}=1, x_{3}=-1$.

$P_B(y)=y^3-3y^2+2y=0 \implies y_{1}=0,y_{2}=1, y_{3}=2$

$A,B$ are symmetric $\implies A,B$ are diagonalizable matrices.

Then, $\exists P_1,P_2 \in \mathbb{M_3(\mathbb{R})}$ (nonsingular matrices) such that $P_1^tAP_1=diag\{0,1,-1\}$,
$ P_2^tBP_2=diag\{0,1,2\}$.

For odd $k$ we get that $(P_1^tAP_2)^k=(P_1^tA^kP_1)=diag\{0^k,1^k,(-1)^k\}=diag\{0,1,-1\}$,

and $(P_2^tBP_2)^k=(P_2^tB^kP_2)=diag\{0^k,1^k,2^k\}=diag\{0,1,2^k\}$

The signatures are different, then $A^k , B^k$ are not congruent for odd $k$.

For even $k$ we get that $(P_1^tAP_2)^k=(P_1^tA^kP_1)=diag\{0^k,1^k,(-1)^k\}=diag\{0,1,1\}$,

and $(P_2^tBP_2)^k=(P_2^tB^kP_2)=diag\{0^k,1^k,2^k\}=diag\{0,1,2^k\}$

The signatures are equals, then $A^k, B^k$ are congruent for even $k$.

Is my solution correct?

Feedback is welcome !

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean with "the signature" ? Two diagonal matrices are congruent over $\Bbb{R}$ (ie. $C=U^\top D U$ for some $U\in GL_n(\Bbb{R})$) iff they have the same number of zero, positive and negative entries.

Comment: That's exactly what i meant

Comment: So that's it, all you need is to prove everything rigorously, diagonalizing symmetric matrices in an orthogonal basis, and when two real diagonal matrices are congruent. Note that you don't need to factorize the characteristic polynomials exactly, all you need is to count the number of positive and negative roots.